# How to setup OpenVPN behind firewall / router

Tags: networking, port, portforwarding, openvpn, forwarding

I try to setup OpenVPN server behind a firewall, but it didn't work as expected.
I suppose my problem is about port forwarding but i don't know how to procede.

Here is my network scheme :
[image: Network scheme]

I tried to port forward on my Modem to my VPN (from * to 192.168.2.200), but it never works.

Can you help me ?

Comment: why the modem also have a private IP? is your modem also a router ?

Comment: Yes but i route all request to my main router / firewall. The router / firewall is a ISA500 if it can help.

Comment: you have to do 2 port forwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done 2 port forward and it works now.

The first one on the model to my router (192.168.2.1)

And the other one on the router to my VPN (192.168.2.200).

Thank for help Vidal.